# Will aborting a Python script corrupt file which is open for read?

Tags: python, file-io, abort

If I run a python script (with Linux) which reads in a file (e.g.: `with open(inputfile) as infi:`): Will the file be in danger when I abort the script by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: @Cyber Assuming from your answer postet as comment - is this question to trivial and shoud i delete it? - Thanks anyway

Comment: @aldorado: I think this is a reasonable question, even if it's a novice question. Cyber should post it as an answer, which you can accept.

Comment: Though it is a short question, with a short answer, I think it is a perfectly valid question. You could leave it up in case others have the same question, which is one of the primary goals of this site. I moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. It will release the file handle when the script stops running. Also you typically only have to worry about corrupting a file when you kill a script that is writing to the file, in case it is interrupted mid-write.

Comment: Since it's really up to the OS, it's possible that some ancient computer with a tape drive might stretch or snap the tape if you canceled a read suddenly, and it's possible that some not-quite-as-ancient computer with an OS that didn't clean up properly after dead processes (like Classic Mac System 6.x) would leak the file handle and leave you unable to open the file until reboot… But in Linux, or anything else modern, you can treat that "probably not" as "no".

Comment: Correct, but I try to avoid absolute statements, as only a sith deals in absolutes :)

Comment: Hard to get more absolute than "Do or do not, there is no try", "Always pass on what you have learned", or "Absolutely not, too old the boy is", "Fear leads to anger, anger leads to hate, hate leads to suffering", or… just about anything Yoda ever said. Maybe Lucas was trying to tell us something about Yoda? :)